# How do I get fullcalendar to read date/time?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am using fullcalendar on my project. My user will enter event information such as event name, date, and location. everything works but the date/time. 
when the user enters date and time it appears like this: 06/28/2016 10:00 AM

FullCalendar reads the date but doesn't read the time.
What do i need to do so that it can read the time?

Here is my js for fullcalendar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here

    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    weekends: true,

    events: 'http://www.familyevent.comli.com/events.php',

    eventRender: function(event) {
      if (event.allDay === 'true') {
        event.allDay = true;
      } else {
        event.allDay = false;
      }

    },
    eventClick: function(event) {
      alert("event start " + moment(event.start).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a') + " event end " +
        moment(event.end).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss'));
    }

  });

});
```

I put in eventClick to see what fullCalendar was reading. it gets the date but the time is always 12:00 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use moment.js that is already bundled with fullCalendar to convert the date to a format that fullcalendar will understand.

```
event.start = moment("06/28/2016 10:00 AM");
```

If it still doesn't work even after removing space before AM, and if your date format is well-defined, you can create the moment object step-by step, by adding the hours and minutes manually:

```
var time = ("06/28/2016 10:00 AM").split(" ")[1].split[":"];
event.start = moment("06/28/2016 10:00 AM").hours(time[0]).minutes(time[1]); //also add AM/PM handling
```

Comment: event.start = moment("06/28/2016 10:00 AM"); works but sets all events to that date and time                                                                          event.start = moment("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"); does not work. why is this?

Comment: You need to specify a format when you do this with moment. Right now you are getting a deprecation warning that Moment falls back to JS date. Your code should be moment("06/28/2016 10:00 AM", 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a')

Comment: that still changes all my events to 6/28/2016 10:00 AM. fullcalendar can read the date but does not read the time. My events in my json feed are like this '2016-06-28T11:00'. it gets the date but the time is missing. it always puts 12:00 am as the time

Comment: The problem was in my json feed. the formatting works now. Thank you